# Why is this error in sim_slopes() occurring after R update?

Tags: r, rlang

I am trying to use the "interactions" package to create a johnson-neyman plot of simple slopes. However, when trying to run the "sim_slopes()" function, I get the following error. Until I updated R to 4.2.2, I did not have this problem. I am on macOS Ventura 13.1.

```
Error:
! `class` must be a character vector, not a list.
Backtrace:
 1. interactions::sim_slopes(...)
 3. jtools:::summ.glm(...)
 4. jtools:::do_robust(model, robust, cluster, data, vcov)
 5. jtools::get_robust_se(...)
 6. jtools::stop_wrap(...)
 8. rlang (local) `<fn>`(class = <named list>)
```

Below is an example of my code, including a simulated dataset you can use to test it.

```
#Simulated Dataset
moderator = c(rbinom(100,2,.5))
predictor = c(rnorm(100,2.5,1))
outcome = c(rnorm(100,17,2))
df = data.frame(moderator,predictor,outcome)

#define model
mod = glm(outcome~predictor*moderator, data=df)#define model

#Load "Interactions" Library to call "sim_slopes()"
library(interactions)
#create jn plot
jnplot = sim_slopes(mod, pred = predictor, modx = moderator, jnplot = TRUE)
```

Below is the error trace function I ran and output.

```r
rlang::last_trace()
# <error/rlang_error>
# Error:
# ! `class` must be a character vector, not a list.
# ---
# Backtrace:
#      ▆
# 1. └─interactions::sim_slopes(...)
# 2.   ├─jtools::summ(...)
# 3.   └─jtools:::summ.glm(...)
# 4.     └─jtools:::do_robust(model, robust, cluster, data, vcov)
# 5.       └─jtools::get_robust_se(...)
# 6.         └─jtools::stop_wrap(...)
# 7.           ├─base::do.call(rlang::abort, abort_args)
# 8.           └─rlang (local) `<fn>`(class = <named list>)
# 9.             └─rlang:::validate_signal_args(...)
#  10.               └─rlang:::check_character(class, call = env)
#  11.                 └─rlang:::stop_input_type(x, what, ..., arg = arg, call = call)
#  12.                   └─rlang::abort(message, ..., call = call, arg = arg)
```

I have tried everything I could find on StackOverflow relevant to this matter, so if you have any advice for my specific problem, that would be much appreciated.

I have tried:

- updating rlang
- updating jtools
- updating the dependencies of both packages
- reinstalling all packages I've installed in the past
- installing and updating XCode
- updating RStudio
- restarting my computer
- checking for package updates
- checking for software updates on my computer

Comment: I don't get the error, so I can't say why you do, but here's how to debug it:  run `debug(jtools::stop_wrap)`, then run the code.   It will stop in the debugger when the `stop_wrap` function is called.  You can single-step through it by hitting `n`.  Just before you get to `do.call(rlang::abort, abort_args)`, print the `abort_args` variable.  Apparently it contains an element named `class` that is a named list.  See if you can figure out why.

Comment: If you can't, then print every argument to `jtools::stop_wrap`, i.e. `list(...)`, `brk`, `trace`, `class`, and `call`, and edit the results into your question.  Maybe someone else here can help.

Comment: I don't get an error either. I would definitely look for package version mismatches.  I have interactions 1.1.5, jtools 2.2.1, rlang 1.0.6 ...

Comment: Huzzah! Printing the abort_args variable let me know I was missing a package called "sandwich," and after installing it, everything works. Thank you thank you thank you!!! And thanks for the advice about debugging in general -- I'll use that moving forward.

Comment: Just for the record: In this GitHub issue the problem has been reported to the maintainer of the `interactions` and `jtools` packages. Hopefully, this helps to avoid the problem in future versions of the package. https://github.com/jacob-long/jtools/issues/132

Answer (score 2):

Printing the abort_args variable let me know I was missing a package called "sandwich," and after installing it, everything works.