# Error of probe_interaction(): ! `class` must be a character vector, not a list

Tags: r

I want to see the interaction of my model of my two groups S and NS. But the errors keeps coming out. I cannot find why. My code was as bellow.

```
lms= lm(RSFC_Agebyd_DAN ~ 1 + Age + d + RT + IO + CR + Age:d + Age:RT + Age:IO + Age:CR, data = S)
lmNS = lm(RSFC_Agebyd_DAN ~ 1 + Age + d + RT + IO + CR + Age:d + Age:RT + Age:IO + Age:CR, data = NS)

probe_interaction(lmS,pred=d, modx=Age)
probe_interaction(lmNS, pred=d, modx=Age)
```

The error message was like this:

> Error:
> ! class must be a character vector, not a list.
> Backtrace:
>
> 1. interactions::probe_interaction(lmNS, pred = d, modx = Age)
> 2. interactions::sim_slopes(model = lmNS, modx = Age, pred = d)
> 3. jtools:::summ.lm(...)
> 4. jtools:::do_robust(model, robust, cluster, data, vcov)
> 5. jtools::get_robust_se(...)
> 6. jtools::stop_wrap(...)
> 7. rlang (local) `<fn>`(class = <named list>)

The environment:

> packageVersion("interactions")
> [1] ‘1.1.5’
> packageVersion("jtools")
> [1] ‘2.2.1’
>
> R version 4.2.2 (2022-10-31) -- "Innocent and Trusting"
> Copyright (C) 2022 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
> Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin17.0 (64-bit)
>
> RStudio 2021.09.2 Build 382
> macOS Mojave version 10.14.6

Thank you in advance

I reinstalled R, Rstudio, packages, ... But nothing worked.

Comment: [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/5325862) on making a reproducible example that is easier for folks to help with. Right now the best anybody can really do is guess: your error message says you supplied something as a list instead of a vector. Have you checked that out?

Comment: Hi camille, thank you for your reply. Yes I noticed. But I don't know which list is it. I found the result of lm() is a list. But the examples given in the help text put the result of lm() into probe_interaction() directly. I think there might be some hidden steps in the probe_interaction() function but I don't know how it works. I can not figure more from their guide : https://rdrr.io/cran/interactions/man/probe_interaction.html

Comment: This question reported a similar error message:  https://stackoverflow.com/q/75120120/2554330 .  I wonder if the solution (installing `sandwich`) would also work for you?

Comment: If you know that `lm` returns a list, then clearly you need to extract the "class" element of that list.

Comment: As a side note:  your attempt to fit a linear model to 10 variables is guaranteed to fail in any case.   Further, how can you have the independent variables include both `Age` and various elements such as `Age:RT` ?  You need to figure out which subsets of your data you actually want to fit here.

Comment: `installing sandwich` works!!!!! Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Hi Carl, thank you for your reply. Age:RT is the interaction of Age and RT

Comment: Just for the record: In this GitHub issue the problem has been reported to the maintainer of the `interactions` and `jtools` packages. Hopefully, this helps to avoid the problem in future versions of the package. https://github.com/jacob-long/jtools/issues/132